# jdk version for compiling java code: jenkins vs pom.xml

Tags: maven, jenkins

We are using jdk 6 to compile our code (specified in jenkins), I am trying to specify jdk 7 to compile the projects from now on. I noticed some of the projects have specified jdk 6 in their pom.xml. I am not sure which one takes precedence when jenkins specifies jdk 7 but pom.xml speicifies jdk 6. Any idea which one takes the final precedence to compile the code?

Comment: Are you asking about target version?

Comment: I want the compiler and the target version to be java 7. When jenkins and mvn both specify a jdk version which one is effective? I couldn't find a concrete answer.

Answer (score 0):

In JDK you can specify the generated class files that target a specified version of the VM. For example if JDK 1.7 is used you can specify the target class file version as 1.7 or lower version.

In maven compiler plugin you can specify the source and target version as follows.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${sourceVersion}</source>
                <target>${targetVersion}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

In your case if you want the class to be compiled to java 1.7 then you have to specify `${sourceVersion}` to 1.7 and the `${targetVersion}` to 1.7

> I am not sure which one takes precedence when jenkins specifies jdk 7 but pom.xml speicifies jdk 1.6

If JDK 7 is used in Jenkins and the target version in the pom is 1.6 then the classes will be compiled to jdk 1.6 version.

Check the following links for more information.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#options

Comment: What is the source exactly? Does jenkins look at source or target in the pom.xml?

Comment: Check -source option in the oracle link in the answer.